# python api missing bpy.types.Cycles*

Tags: python, scripting, documentation

In 2.81 python api the `bpy.types.Cycles*` classes are omitted from docs but mostly still accessible ?

Can they be found elsewhere in the docs ?

Comment: Good question, I'll ask Aaron Carlisle if that was intentional.

Comment: Aaron pointed out to me that there is currently an issue open regarding `bpy.types.CyclesRenderSettings`: https://developer.blender.org/T68050

Answer (score 1):

Till there is no changes you can use API reference form 2.80, for example [CyclesRenderSettings](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.80/bpy.types.CyclesRenderSettings.html)

Source of Cycles types contains in *Blender_installation_path\2.8*\scripts\addons\cycles\properties.py*, you can use it as reference simultaneously.